# Google OAuth 2.0 implementation - registration

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In the Google developer console, when you create new app credentials for use in OAuth 2.0, and you specify a web app, it requests that you register callback URI and JavaScript origins.

I don't have a precise understanding of the need to register these.

For the callback URI, presumably this prevents a 3rd party who presents a malicious page to a user from getting the authorization code. However, the client id and secret are still hidden in the app server, so isn't the malicious application unable to do anything anyway?

Furthermore, if the callback URI is already registered, what does registering the JS origins separately accomplish. Unlike the callback URI registration, this is not mentioned by the OAuth 2.0 spec, it's something Google chose to implement.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you request a token, that token will be passed to the callback URL. By only permitting callback URLs that you have configured in the API console, you are preventing malicious users from spoofing the request and having the token sent to a third party. I suspect the aspect of OAuth that you've missed is that the callback is sent via a browser redirect, so is easy to fake.

Callback URLs are part of the OAuth server flow.

JS Origins come into play when you are using the client (Javascript) OAuth flow. They ensure that any OAuth request has come from a page that originated on your site.

The server flow is ...

[image]

Comment: Regarding the callback URLs in the server flow, the request for a token would also have to send the client_id and client_secret. So the token request without these pieces of information would not return a token. So is there a loss of security?

Comment: p.s. Thanks for addressing the JS origins - I wasn't sure why you would need to have both JS origins and callback, but I see that google has one registration page for web apps that will use either server/client flow.

Still hope to understand the added security from registering the callback in advance. Thanks!

Comment: in the server flow, the client details are sent from your server to google over https. See the flow diagram I added to the answer.

Comment: Right...I'm still not seeing the added security of registering the redirect URL. A malicious user can have the _authorization code_ sent to a 3rd party. However, without providing the client_id and client_secret, how could a malicious user obtain the token.

Comment: Referring to the diagram above, the "Exchange code for token" includes the secret and a redirect url. If the redirect was spoofed, the token response (which could be an enduring refresh token) would go to the malicious site,

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I understand a bit more from reading the spec. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6

It is to prevent an attack by a **user of the same client** An attacker can create an account at the same client and initiate auth flow, but he replaces the redirect URI with his own URI.

He then tricks a victim into following the link to authorize the same legit client they are using. However, the auth code is now sent to the attacker URI.

The attacker then completes the flow by providing the auth code back to the client, which the client uses to complete the flow obtaining the token. However, this token may be associated by the client with the attacker, allowing him to impersonate the victim.

Comment: agree, but for completeness: that attack is not restricted to attackers that are users of the same client; any attacker can do this

Comment: Hey Hans, I'm not sure how an attacker from a _different_ client would get access to the client id and secret? This was my question in the conversation above. The attack described in the spec assumes same client, so there's one set of client credentials.

Comment: ok, maybe I just misunderstood: I meant to say that the attacker does not need to have an **account** at the client (which is often a good start for attacks on other accounts at that same client), but I guess you meant by "user of the same client" that the attacker just applies the attack through the same client that the victim wants to use; in the latter case I agree